how to fix the alignment of the comment's Text?
I want to put the comment's text underneath the user image like this layout:
What should I do to get the required output like the image?
the comment's text should start underneath the user image , my output is showing the comment's text next to it not underneath it , what is the problem? or what did I miss? please point me to the right approach


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  addDefaultComment(); // Add a default comment when the page loads
  keepDropdownOpen(); // Keep the dropdown open by default
});

function toggleDropdown() {
  const dropdownContent = document.getElementById("dropdownContent");
  dropdownContent.classList.toggle("show");
}

function keepDropdownOpen() {
  const dropdownContent = document.getElementById("dropdownContent");
  dropdownContent.classList.add("show"); // Keep the dropdown open by default
}

function addComment() {
  const commentText = document.getElementById("commentText").value;
  if (commentText.trim() === "") return;

  createCommentElement(commentText, "زائر"); // Replace "زائر" with actual user name if available

  document.getElementById("commentText").value = "";
}

function createCommentElement(commentText, userName) {
  const commentList = document.getElementById("commentsList");
  const newComment = document.createElement("div");
  newComment.classList.add("comment-card");

  const userImage = document.createElement("img");
  userImage.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/40"; // Placeholder image
  newComment.appendChild(userImage);

  const commentContent = document.createElement("div");
  commentContent.classList.add("comment-content");

  const commentHeader = document.createElement("div");
  commentHeader.classList.add("comment-header");

  const userNameElement = document.createElement("span");
  userNameElement.classList.add("user-name");
  userNameElement.innerText = userName;
  commentHeader.appendChild(userNameElement);

  const commentDate = document.createElement("span");
  commentDate.classList.add("comment-date");
  const date = new Date();
  commentDate.innerText = `${date.toLocaleDateString()} ${date.toLocaleTimeString()}`;
  commentHeader.appendChild(commentDate);

  commentContent.appendChild(commentHeader);

  // Add a line break after the comment header
  const lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
  commentContent.appendChild(lineBreak);

  const commentTextElement = document.createElement("div");
  commentTextElement.classList.add("comment-text");
  commentTextElement.innerText = commentText;

  commentContent.appendChild(commentTextElement);
  newComment.appendChild(commentContent);

  commentList.appendChild(newComment);
}


function addDefaultComment() {
  const defaultCommentText = "هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!";
  createCommentElement(defaultCommentText, "زائر");
}

document.getElementById("commentText").addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default action of the Enter key
    addComment();
  }
});
.comments-container {
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.dropdown-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.dropdown-container:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.dropdown-container .arrow {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox='0 0 140 140' width='24' height='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><g><path d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' fill='black'/></g></svg>") no-repeat;
  background-position: right 5px top 50%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown-content.show {
  display: block;
}

.comment-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.comment-card img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.comment-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.comment-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.comment-header .user-name {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #000;
}

.comment-header .comment-date {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #888;
}

.comment-text {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.add-comment-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #0056b3;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 35px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.add-comment-button:hover {
  background-color: #004494;
}

.comment-input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.comment-input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 60px;
}
<div class="custom-box">
  <div class="comments-container">
    <div class="dropdown-container p" onclick="toggleDropdown()">
      <span class="mt-1">التعليقات</span>
      <span class="arrow mt-1"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="dropdownContent" class="dropdown-content">
      <h3>إضافة تعليق</h3>
      <div class="comment-input-container">
        <input type="text" id="commentText" class="comment-input" />
      </div>
      <button onclick="addComment()" class="add-comment-button"> أضف </button>
      <div id="commentsList"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




I made a snippet. I moved the } from the end to right after .comments-container {   padding-bottom: 0px !important;} 

Your .comment-card is a flex container using row as the direction.
The behavior of flex is to force all of its children to align according to the specified direction. Hence it is described as one-dimensional.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox
Option 1: You could take your img out of the flex container.
Option 2: Use grid instead of flex.
Option 3: Change flex direction to column (this may however likely lead to another display issue.

As i can see the image is right above the text, Just apply the CSS text-align:right; to .comment-card class that will solve it.


.comments-container {
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.dropdown-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.dropdown-container:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.dropdown-container .arrow {
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 50px;
    color: black;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox='0 0 140 140' width='24' height='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><g><path d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' fill='black'/></g></svg>")
        no-repeat;
    background-position: right 5px top 50%;
}

.dropdown-content {
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown-content.show {
    display: block;
}

.comment-card {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.comment-card img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.comment-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.comment-user-date {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.comment-header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.comment-header .user-name {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #000;
}

.comment-header .comment-date {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #888;
}

.comment-text {
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.add-comment-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #0056b3;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 35px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 42px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.add-comment-button:hover {
    background-color: #004494;
}

.comment-input-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.comment-input {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 60px;
}
<div class="custom-box">
    <div class="comments-container">
        <div class="dropdown-container p" onclick="toggleDropdown()">
            <span class="mt-1">التعليقات</span>
            <span class="arrow mt-1"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdownContent" class="dropdown-content">
            <h3>إضافة تعليق</h3>
            <div class="comment-input-container">
                <input type="text" id="commentText" class="comment-input"/>
            </div>
            <button onclick="addComment()" class="add-comment-button">
                أضف
            </button>
            <div id="commentsList">
                <div class="comment-card">
                    <div class="comment-user-date">
                        <div class="comment-header">
                            <span class="user-name">زائر</span>
                            <span class="comment-date">8/8/2024 5:32:52 pm</span>
                        </div>
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/40">
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-content">
                        <br>
                        <div class="comment-text">
                            نا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!هنا يجب أن يكون التعليق!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





this didn't exactly work, what i want dear sir is to have the picture on the right side the username and the date time on the other end of the line and underneath that the comment's text

@nabil1997 Please check the above snippet

@Akash Please fix the snippet. You split the CSS

it's also almost right , thank you dear sir for your time, the alignment is almost correct, the thing missing is that i need the user image to be in the same line as the username and date time, what do you advise me to do?

Can you add "comment-header" class (which is new class that cover both username and date and time, parent will be class="comment-card")
and place it above the user image? so that we can set it using CSS
.comment-head {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.comment-header {
display: flex;
justify-content: start;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 0;
}

i didn't get your exact thoughts sorry for that, can you please show me what you mean in you answer above ?

i guess i did what you suggested sir, but that took the username and date time above the user image , i want instead to have the image and username and date time on the same line and underneath them the comment's text

@nabil1997 i have update the snippet as per your requirement please check it. For ease i have removed the JS part from the code cause i don't know how to add those divs from the JS, it's just HTML and CSS for your reference.



#a{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}

#b{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
}
<div id = 'a'>
   <div id = 'b'>
      <div>user name</div>
      <div>date</div>
   </div>

   <div >text</div>

</div>



